# "guides", "colourbar" and "keyheight" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot2 I made a barplot in which each bars are filled with a gradient.
My problem concerns the legend of the plot. It is a bar filled with the same colour gradient:

```
scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "lightpurple",
    high = "black",
    limits = c(0, max(graph$y)),
    "colourbar")
```

When I wanted to change the height of the legend bar I tried that instead:

```
scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "lightpurple",
    high = "black",
    limits = c(0, max(graph$y)),
    guides("colourbar", guide_legend(keyheight = 2))
```

But nothing changed.
And when I precise only the height of the bar without the colour gradient, the height is correct.

```
scale_fill_gradient(
    low = "lightpurple",
    high = "black",
    limits = c(0, max(graph$y)),
    guide = guide_legend(keyheight = 2))
```

What did I do wrong when mentioning both "colourbar" and "height" in "guides"?

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible, i.e., give use some dummy data and the code to produce the plot so that we can test solutions.

Comment: The guides syntax should be `guides(colourbar = guide_legend(keyheight = 2))`

Comment: perhaps `barheight`, not `keyheight` for `colorbar`.